# How to create a new Kubernetes cluster on Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I can't seem to figure out how to create a totally new Kubernetes cluster on a Docker Desktop running instance on my computer. (It shouldn't matter if this was a Mac or PC).

I know how to -set- the current cluster context, but I only have one cluster so I can't set anything else.

```
### What's my current context pointing to?
$ kubectl config current-context
docker-for-desktop

### Set the context to be "docker-for-desktop" cluster
$ kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop
Switched to context “docker-for-desktop”
```

Further questions:

1. If I have multiple clusters, then only one of them (the currently 'set' one) will be running at once with the other's stopped/sleeping?
2. Clusters are independent from each other, so if i can muck around and play with one cluster, then this should not impact another cluster

Comment: You need to make sure that Kubernetes is running. Check in the UI wether kubernetes is turned off. in that case turn it on and wait that the cluster is deployed.

Comment: Thanks @Mazzy for the comment. Yep, it's installed and running. The clue to that was `kubectl config current-context` reports the current context. So yep - that's all working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes config file describes 3 objects: **clusters**, **users**, and **contexts**.

**cluster** - cluster name + details - the host and the certificates.

**user** - user name and credentials, to authorise you against any cluster host.

the **context** role is to make the connection between a **user** and a **cluster**, so when you use that context,`kubectl` will authorise you against the cluster specified in the context object, using the credentials of the user specified in the context object. an example `context` object:

```
apiVersion: v1
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}

clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: xxxxxxxxx
    server: xxxxxxxxx
  name: gke_dev-yufuyjfvk_us-central1-a_standard-cluster-1

users:
- name: efrat-dev
  user:
    client-certificate: xxxxxxxxx
    client-key: xxxxxxxxx

contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_dev-yufuyjfvk_us-central1-a_standard-cluster-1
    user: efrat-dev
  name: gke-dev
```

the `kubectl config` subcommand has a set of commands to [generate cluster, user & context entries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) in the config file.

**multiple k8s clusters from docker-desktop**

under the hood, when you enable k8s, docker desktop downloads kubernetes components as docker images, and the server listens `https://localhost:6443`. it is all done automatically so unless you have any intention to run the entire structure by yourself i dont suppose you can configure it to run multiple clusters.

**about your further questions:**

when you set a context, `kubectl` will set `current-context` to that one, and every `kubectl` you run will go to the context's cluster, using the context's user credentials. it doesnt mean the clusters are dead. it wont affect them at all.

Comment: As always - anything kubernetes related is a cluster fk of complexity, even for simplish things :( But cheers for the helpful answer, @efratlevitan

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the checkbox is enabled

[image]

Comment: My question wasn't about wether or not K8's was running ... but how to create _another_ cluster.

Comment: Protip: if you're going to include macOS window screens on SO hold down `option` when talking the screenshot to remove the alpha border gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Using Docker Desktop you can create multiple clusters using a development tool such as [k3d](https://k3d.io). Disable Kubernetes under Docker Desktop preferences as you won't need it for this. Then install XCode CLT, Homebrew and use Brew to install k3d locally. Next issue the commands:

```bash
k3d cluster create one && \
k3d cluster create two
```

This will create two clusters, automatically switching contexts. Run `k3d cluster list` to list available clusters and use `k3d --help` for online help. A more in-depth tutorial [is available](https://vhs.codeberg.page/post/kubernetes-macos-k3s-k3d-rancher/) for macOS without fee.

Comment: Points for mentioning `k3d`. Unfortunately the link you added appears to be broken. The v5.3.0 documentation for `k3d` can be found [here](https://k3d.io/v5.3.0/).

Comment: @JonTurner Thanks for noting the linkrot. Fixed.