# Docker desktop how to create new k8s cluster context

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have Docker Desktop and I want to create multiple clusters so I can work on different projects. For example cluster name 1: hello and cluster name 2: world.

I currently have one cluster with the context of docker-desktop that actually working.

Comment: Could you use multiple Kubernetes namespaces to achieve this?  Or, there are tools separate from Docker Desktop like [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io) or [KinD](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) that would help you create multiple local clusters with a little more control over the setup.

Comment: I concern that if I create different namespaces things can get mixed up, because sometimes I have different namespaces for things that can be used by many other namespaces in different projects. The solid way of work should be a completely different cluster for each development project. I tried Minikube but it gets so many issues and I found that Docker Desktop works perfect. I mean, couldn't run the Minikube properly..

Comment: I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718446/how-to-create-a-new-kubernetes-cluster-on-docker-desktop) with useful answers under it. Are any of these answers helpful to you?

Comment: I have tried the instruction followed in the top question there, unfortunately it didn't work. I only got error that the new cluster I locally created was not attached to any node. So it was a "blank" cluster. I tried for hours how to figure out how to add node and couldn't. I did namespaces instead after all which I don't really like

Comment: Did you consider using a development tool such as [k3d](https://k3d.io/) on Docker Desktop?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Actually yes. I have found a tool called Kind which is very easy to use, enabling easy creation of multiple different clusters on the local machine.
It wraps the Kubernetes core elements in Docker. Read more here: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/

Answer (score 1):

To clarify I am posting Community Wiki answer.

A tool `kind` met your expectations in this case.

> [kind](https://sigs.k8s.io/kind) is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container “nodes”.   kind was primarily designed for testing Kubernetes itself, but may be used for local development or CI.

Here one can find User Guide to this tool.
One can install it with 5 ways:

- [With A Package Manager](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#installing-with-a-package-manager)
- [From Release Binaries](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#installing-from-release-binaries)
- [From Source](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#installing-from-source)
- [With ***make***](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#installing-with-make)
- [With  ***go get***  /  ***go install***](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#installing-with-go-get--go-install)

To create cluster with this tool run:

```
kind create cluster
```

To specify another image use the `--image` flag:

```
kind create cluster --image=xyz
```

In `kind` the node-image is built off the base-image, that installs all the dependencies required for Docker and Kubernetes to run in a container.

To assign the cluster a different name than `kind`, use  `--name` flag.

More uses can be found with with:

```
kind create cluster --help
```